# How to render jsx in tanstack table column

Tags: react-table, tanstack

I am using tanstack react-table library. How can I render a jsx element in the table column. I was trying to use the accessorFn to return jsx but I get an object in the browser.

```
interface RetailPriceTableColumnDef {
    commodity: string;
    country: string;
    price: number;
    date: string;
    emoji: string;
}

const columns: ColumnDef<RetailPriceTableColumnDef>[] = [
    {
        accessorKey: 'commodity',
        header: 'Commodity',
    },
    {
        header: 'Country',
        accessorFn: (row) => {
            return <CountryWithEmoji emoji={row.emoji} name={row.country} />;
        },
    },
    {
        accessorKey: 'price',
        header: 'Retail Price ($Kg)',
    },
    {
        accessorKey: 'date',
        header: 'Last Updated',
    },
];

export const RetailPricesTable = () => {
    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(LatestRetailPricesDocument, {
        variables: {
            groupId: 1,
            commodityIds: 1,
        },
    });
    return <div>{data && <DataTable columns={columns} data={data?.latestRetailPrices} />}</div>;
};
```

I want to render this column using jsx

```
{
            header: 'Country',
            accessorFn: (row) => {
                return <CountryWithEmoji emoji={row.emoji} name={row.country} />;
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render jsx with `cell` and `header` key in the column object.

https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/column-def#cell
https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/column-def#header

Here is an example:

```js
const columns: ColumnDef<RetailPriceTableColumnDef>[] = [
    {
        accessorKey: 'commodity',
        header: () => {
          return <h1>Commodity</h1>
        }
    },
    {
        header: 'Country',
        cell: ({ row }) => {
            return <CountryWithEmoji emoji={row.emoji} name={row.country} />;
        },
    },
```